# Efficiently access a large array from a Function

Tags: php, function, scope

I have the following PAGE STRUCTURE within a game.

PAGE 1
**callGameEngine.php** (which returns game output (JSON array), $gameInfo2return, via ajax), in terms of this problem, we can see it requires the game engine page, and then sends the game engine the relevant parameters...

```
 require 'gameEngine.php'; //includes only engine() function
$gameInfo2return = engine ($parameter1,$parameter2,ecc);
echo $gameInfo2return;//the AJAX return
```

PAGE 2 **gameEngine.php** (the engine itself which obvioulsy produces many variables, arrays etc etc on a long loop)

Two of the ARRAYS are large 2d arrays, both 40 by 60 (last value is array[39][59]) These arrays represent the land of the game, so a terrain 40km by 60km. ($bigTerrainArray). They are referenced continously but dont need to be modified. Because they are so large I don't want to produce copies of them by passing them directly to functions but want to access them as globals.

```
$bigTerrainArray = (array 40x60);
```

This page also utilises another page, engineFunctions.php,

```
require 'engineFunctions.php'; //including a function lets call bomb().
$goodBomb = bomb($xCoOrd,$yCoOrd);
```

PAGE 3 **engineFunctions.php****AND HERE IS THE PROBLEM... to not pass the big arrays as a variable I want to access them as globals. But a function here will not understand global.. so what can i do?

```
function bomb ($xCoOrd,$yCoOrd){

    global $bigTerrainArray;
etc etc etc

}
```

**The problem is**

1     **scope** , because this structure doesn-t work, the variable $bigTerrainArray cannot be accessed via global, because nesting functions like this and then calling global wont work, so how can i accesss $bigTerrainArray?

and

2     **efficiency**, what is the most efficient way to keep accessing $bigTerrainArray?

Comment: your question is barely understandable. Please rephrase the question so that we can easily understand it. Explain everything step by step instead of hopping trough scripts that nobody can understand without knowing the context

Comment: @Thomas, ok sorry. Any parts in particular that are confusing?

Comment: Looks like PHP3 code, terrible! Have a look into PHP5, OOP. Using design patterns would improve efficiency, using classes would resolve scope problems.

Comment: @Dan, converting all to OOP would be the IDEAL solution, but not feasible for now.

Comment: You are jumbling your scope totally. I don't think you'll be able to keep track of what's going on in your code this way. At least not for a long while.

NEVER jumble up the scope. When you can't immediately see where a variable comes from, it should make your alarm bells ring.
Pass variables as arguments for example.

NEVER use global. The usage of global indicates a horrible scoping and is a result of what I have said in the previous paragraph.

Most of your problems can be solved with a good object oriented design as @DanFromGermany already stated.

Comment: @Thomas, thanks I know you are right, and normally I would avoid global. But here I have to access these large arrays many times a second all through the game loop. If I pass the functions these arrays aren-t creating copies of them?

Comment: @Gamemorize, have you tried passing by reference?